# How to Create a New Folder for Downloading a File

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

I want to download folder that client side (browser) make.

I considered using [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/), but I can't find how to make folder.

For example, some png make from html canvas put one folder, I want to save this folder with download dialog.

I want to use a folder for some file to one folder.and I must download only once.

Please advise me.

html

```
<a download='folder' href='#' onclick="Download()">download</a>
```

Comment: you just asked this a while ago and then deleted it, why didnt you just edit the question? You need to be more clear in what you are wanting.

Comment: Sorry. I was freaked out.

Comment: Where is the folder coming from? A server? FTP? MVC? your tags are all client side stuff. Need to know that.

Comment: Nowhere.Browzer(not server) make the folder.I want to download this folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FSO.js](http://fsojs.com/), but be warned that it currently only works in Chrome. Additionally, the folders you create can only really be accessed from within your webapp (for example, you can't choose to write a specific folder on the C drive).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, You can't really interact with the local system or the server with JavaScript because of security. You can call a server-side script with JavaScript, via AJAX.

If you don't care, you can check out [Javascript FSO CreateFolder Method](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-FSO-CreateFolder-Method.aspx)

JavaScript Example...

```
// initialize ActiveXObject and create an object of Scripting.FileSystemObject.  
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  

// creates a folder with specified name at the specified location  
fso.CreateFolder("C:\\Temp\\myFolder");  

fso = null;
```

Comment: Worth noting that this will only work in IE and only when you have set your security settings in an insane way.

Comment: You are not suppose to interact with the local system or the server file system via JavaScript because of IMMENSE security threats. This is a hack around. The correct way is to get the server to run a script, creating a folder on the local machine.