# Create a folder on client machine from asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

I have a very silly question, Can I create a Folder in Client machine from a web application. I have tried to do that.

But I am unable to do so. I have created an asp.net web application using visual studio IDE. And when I executed the web application using visual studio the folder is created.

After that I hosted the web application in IIS and the tried to access the web application. The web application was accessed successfully but the folder was not created on the client machine.

Could you please suggest me the ways of how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: You can not do this. And any solution suggesting this need to have feasibility study done as it is potential risk to client. Check your requirement again.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is a framework for creating web sites. The application using ASP.NET is deployed to a web server, for instance IIS. **When ASP code behind of aspx/ascx files or C# code of external components is called it's executed on the web server** (IIS).

I assume you have implemented the code for creating a folder with C# code. This code is, as I said, executed on server. **On your development machine you have client (which is web browser) and server (whis is IIS) on the same machine. So the folder was created.**

**When you have deployed the application to a separate web server then you separated web server from client. I think your IIS hosted application has created a folder on the machine where IIS were installed. Not on your local machine.**

**If you want to create a folder on client side you shouldn't use C# ASP.NET code.**

You should do some research how to achieve it in other technology. Here's some link for it - [How to Create a New Folder for Downloading a File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335988/how-to-create-a-new-folder-for-downloading-a-file)

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing my all doubts and making me aware of how asp.net web application works.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer was correct I'd be grateful if you would accept it.